# Is it possible to have SQL Server system messages in different language than formats etc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to have date formats etc. in Norwegian, but I want the system messages in English.

Using `SET LANGUAGE` as suggested to other similar questions changes both. So that does not work for me.

Does anyone know if it is at all possible? And if so, how?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: It's usually best to not rely upon the implicit conversions that SQL Server is performing when the format matters - once you're explicitly controlling the formats (either when converting at the SQL Server level or more usually at a presentation layer) it doesn't matter what *defaults* SQL Server would have applied.